# MySQL inserting data in wrong order

Tags: mysql, database, insert

After the order completion, I get the following response from my payment processor

```
Receipt_ID1, Order_ID1, Data_1
```

I insert these values in the same sequence in my MySQL table successfully. But sometimes when there are **two orders** performed within 1-2 secs of each other, the **Data Values**  get inserted in the wrong way in the table. The Data Values interchange. I get the following result

```
Receipt_ID1, Order_ID1, Data_2
Receipt_ID2, Order_ID2, Data_1
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how can I make sure I insert the right Data Value in the right Receipt?

OK these are the actual sequence of the SQL statements -

```
$new_order_id_query = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE ORDERS";
$new_order_id = $row['Auto_increment'];
```

That is how I get the New Order ID from the Orders table and send it to the Payment Processor. Then I receive the Response Array and break it down and do a simple Insert Statement like so

```
INSERT INTO Receipts Values(ReceiptID, OrderID, Data) Values ($Receipt_ID, $Order_ID, $Data);
```

Hope that explains it better!

Comment: are you pulling back *insert ids*, or just hoping that the *auto increment* fields will match? could you post your 3 SQL statements into your question?

Comment: I have edited the question and added some more info that might help you. If it helps, I am using an OScommerce Payment module.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are messing up your variables in your PHP code.

Comment: It works 98/100 times but like I said, only when there are two orders done very quickly, this happens...

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a record into the table you should fetch the id with `mysqli_insert_id` or `PDO::lastInsertId()`. That is the only way to be 100% sure to get the id that is generated for that insert.